# How to transfer from originated contract in Babylon

Tags: transactions, tezos-client

I'm trying to transfer from an originated contract and built the transaction as explained [here](http://tezos.gitlab.io/master/protocols/005_babylon.html):

```
tezos-client transfer 0 from tz1xxx to KT1xxx \
            --entrypoint 'do' \
            --arg '{ DROP ; NIL operation ; PUSH key_hash tz1xxx ; IMPLICIT_ACCOUNT ; PUSH mutez 10000 ; UNIT ; TRANSFER_TOKENS ; CONS }' -D
```

However, I receive the following error message:

```
Invalid primitive:
  1: { DROP ;
  2:   NIL operation ;
  3:   PUSH key_hash tz1xxx ;
  4:   IMPLICIT_ACCOUNT ;
  5:   PUSH mutez 10000 ;
  6:   UNIT ;
  7:   TRANSFER_TOKENS ;
  8:   CONS }
Primitive tz1xxx has invalid case.
Fatal error:
  transfer simulation failed
```

What do I need to change to build a valid transaction?

Comment: If you're just trying to figure out how to use your pre-Babylon `KT1` account, see also this question for suggestions: [How to transfer off of KT1 after Babylon upgrade?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/how-to-transfer-off-of-kt1-after-babylon-upgrade)

Comment: Yes, I was trying that indeed. I could solve this issue by following the advise in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace `PUSH key_hash tz1xxx` by `PUSH key_hash "tz1xxx"` (note the double quotes).

However, the client should be smart enough to understand `tezos-client transfer 1000 from KT1xxx to tz1xxx`.