# How to transfer off of KT1 after Babylon upgrade?

Tags: wallets, delegating, kt1, babylon

For Babylon protocol upgrade, all KT1 accounts delegations are converted to a smart contract [manager.tz](https://tezos.gitlab.io/master/protocols/005_babylon.html#replace-kt1-accounts-with-manager-tz-script).

If I want to transfer off of the KT1 account(s), What are some ways to transfer to a tz account? Are there wallets that supports this migration? How do you do this transfer using `tezos-client` with a node?

Comment: I’m just wondering does it matter which tz1 account is used? Ie should the funds be transferred to a fresh tz1 account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can still be done from the terminal using the normal `./tezos-client transfer <amount> from <src> to <dst>` command, with a couple of important caveats:

1. There is [currently a regression in Babylon](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/592) in that this command expects the value for `amount` to be in `mutez` rather than in `tez`, but only when transferring from a `KT1` account. For example, if you want to send `1.5 tez` you would enter the amount as `1500000`. EDIT: This has since been fixed.
2. The manager `tz1` account must have enough funds in it to cover any transaction fees.

Removing funds from your `KT1` account to its manager `tz1` account can also be accomplished, e.g., in the [Galleon Wallet](https://galleon-wallet.tech/) v0.9.0b by following these steps:

1. Open or restore your wallet.
2. Select your `KT1` account on the sidebar.
3. Select the `Manage Delegation` tab.
4. Use the `Withdraw` option to send funds from the `KT1` to the manager `tz1` account.

The wallet UI takes care of entering the amount correctly, but the `tz1` account still needs to have enough funds to cover any transaction fees.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use latest version of Galleon to widhraw all XTZ from KT1 to tz1, but the transaction stays in "pending" forever and is never recorded in the blockchain. Any way to get out the XTZ?

Comment: @JoaoPereira I would suggest you make sure you have funds in the `tz1` account and just keep trying until it works. Or perhaps try another wallet.